# VS Code debugger error: Windows cannot find 'C:\Program'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

#### Summary

- Goal: to debug a C++ program I am working on.
- Expected Results: After configuration, debugger runs to breakpoint and shows current state of variables, etc.
- Actual Results: When trying to run the debugger on C++ code in VS Code, I get the error in the title. The pop up happens during the pre-launch build task:

The interruption occurs here:

```
 *  Executing task: cd C:\Users\wesle\source\repos\raycast/build && cmake --build . --config Debug 

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.2+f32259642 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  cuda_test.vcxproj -> C:\Users\wesle\source\repos\raycast\build\Debug\cuda_test.exe
```

#### Code:

I am using the auto-generated debug configuration for the Windows (launch) option, with the only addition being a preLaunchTask:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(Windows) Launch",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/Debug/cuda_test.exe",
            "args": [],
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

and this simple tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cd ${workspaceFolder}/build && cmake --build . --config Debug"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Question:

How do I fix this?

#### Things I tried:

1. I think it might be because, somewhere, a path to `"C:/Program Files/..."` is being called without the surrounding quotes, and the space is an issue. However, I have searched for a reference to the Program Files directory in all of the following. Nowhere does a reference exist in these files:

   - settings.json
   - launch.json
   - c_cpp_properties.json
   - tasks.json
2. Another thing I tried was to delete the `tasks.json` file completely and pre-build with debug configuration from the command line. I thought maybe cmake was being replaced with its full, unquoted path via the path env variable. The error persisted (actually popped up a little faster).
3. I have uninstalled all plugins, except the C++ Tools and CMake Tools extensions.
4. I have uninstalled and reinstalled the C++ and CMake extensions.
5. I am most definitely running an instance of VS Code started from the developer console.

#### Notes

1. The error is not present in the text output console. It is a system pop-up box. I don't know if this might be a clue:

[image]

2. The build command in the pre-launch task works fine from the command line.

Comment: If a path has spaces or other nasty characters, enclose the path in double quotes.  For example: "C:\Program Files\x86".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews As I mentioned under the section "Things I have tried", this has already been done, as there are no instances with nasty characters or spaces.

Comment: And to @ThomasMatthews and all upvoting his comment, please read the "things I tried" section. It should become readily apparent that I already considered this. Please take the time to read the question in full, as I took the time to meet all requirements of posting a question according to the standards of this site.

Comment: @rocksNwaves: 1) I completely agree.  There are many reasons to choose VSCode over MSVS.  Including "My boss told me to".  2) Clearly, at least *ONE* of your environment variables (or a CMake variable) expands to a path with a space (e.g. "C:\Program Files" or "C:\Program Files (x86)".  SUGGESTION: Enable CMake "verbose mode", e.g. `--trace, --trace-expand, and --trace-source=some_cmake_source`

Comment: @273K There is a difference between using build tools for compilation and using the IDE. vxxproj extension files are generated for compilation by CMake. It in no way implies that I'm using or have installed the Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: @paulsm4 Yeah, you are right. I just don't know where else to look. Maybe I should edit the question to ask "where else might I look for such a path", because I think that is the issue too.

Comment: Assuming you've looked at everything in VSCode ... look at the files in "build\*, and try enabling "trace" info in CMake.

Comment: These are among the most annoying of problems to remotely debug. Most of the time they only way to figure out what information needs to be in the question to make it answerable is to have already answered your own question. Is there any way you can break down the stages so you can at least narrow down which of them's trying to eat the suspected bad path? You can build properly, can you not? If you can, you can also discard CMake and friends from the problem set. Where is the debugger itself installed?

Answer (score 2):

This problem drives me crazy too. After changing `"console": "externalTerminal"` to `"console": "internalConsole"`, the problem is partially solved (except that everything is shown in vscode's DEBUG CONSOLE).

I don't know why `externalTerminal` is not OK, nowhere mentions it in the documentation.